# Is there a way to validate an SMTP configuration using Zend-Mail?

Tags: php, magento, zend-mail

I have been working on a class in PHP to send out mail and I decided to use the Zend framework.  This class sends out mail using a user's SMTP configuration.  As of right now I am checking a user's SMTP configuration by using the supplied user credentials, and sending out a "dummy" email to a "dummy" email address, and catching the `ZendException` class that may be thrown on error.  This is a horrible method, because of many reasons:

- The SMTP user get's banned eventually for suspected "Spamming" (GMail)
- Inefficient and time consuming
- Failed email delivery attempt is in user's mailbox

**The following is an example of what I am doing right now to test if a SMTP configuration is valid:**

```
public function validSMTP () {
    // Get the user's SMTP configuration
    $config = $this->getConfiguration ();
    // Create a new Zend transport SMTP object
    $transport = new Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp ( $config ["hostname"], [
        "auth"      =>  "login",
        "ssl"       =>  $config ["protocol"],
        "port"      =>  $config ["port"],
        "username"  =>  $config ["from"],
        "password"  =>  $config ["password"]
    ]);
    // Create a new message and send it to dummy email
    $mail = new Zend_Mail ("UTF-8");
    $mail->setBodyText ( "null" );
    $mail->setFrom ( $config ["from"] );
    $mail->addTo ( "dev@null.com" );
    $mail->setSubject ( "Test" );
    // Attempt to send the email
    try {
        // Send the email out
        $mail->send ( $transport );
        // If all is well, return true
        return true;
    }
    // Catch all Zend exceptions
    catch ( Zend_Exception $exception ) {
        // Invalid configuration
        return false;
    }
}
```

So my question is:  Is there a better way of doing this?  Does **Zend_Mail** have a built in feature like this?  I have looked all over and couldn't find anything build-in into **Zend_Mail**.  Thank you in advance to whoever answers!

Comment: BTW, your configuration options don't look like the examples at https://docs.zendframework.com/zend-mail/transport/smtp-authentication/#examples.

Comment: The getConfiguration method is a custom one in my class, it just returns an associative array with the user's configuration.  Other than that, I can't see what can be invalid.  It works on my end.  Perhaps it is different because I am using Zend_Mail within Magento?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to check manually, I will post the end result below so it may help someone in the future.  Thanks to @Barmar for helping me search through the documentation and coming to the result that the **Zend_Mail** framework doesn't support such a feature.  The below methods only work for SSL unfortunately since TLS involves encrypting after the EHLO command (and much more).  If the configuration is valid, then it returns *true*, otherwise it returns the reason it is invalid in string form.

```
public function validSMTP () {
        // Initialize client configuration, for this example
        $config = [
            "hostname"     =>     "smtp.gmail.com",
            "port"         =>     465,
            "protocol"     =>     "ssl",
            "username"     =>     "USERNAME",
            "password"     =>     "PASSWORD",
        ];
        // Add the connection url based on protocol
        $config ["url"] = $config ["protocol"] . "://" . $config ["hostname"];
        // Open a new socket connection to the SMTP mail server
        if ( !( $socket = fsockopen ( $config ["url"], $config ["port"], $en, $es, 15 ) ) ) {
            // Could not establish connection to host
            return "Connection failed, check hostname/port?";
        }
        // Make sure that the protocol is correct
        if ( $this->status_match($socket, '220') === false ) {
            // Probably a wrong protocol (SSL/TLS)
            return "Connection failed, check protocol?";
        }
        // Send hello message to server
        fwrite ( $socket, "EHLO " . $config ["hostname"] ."\r\n" );
        if ( $this->status_match ( $socket, "250" ) === false ) {
            // If Hello fails, say config is invalid
            return "Invalid SMTP configuration";
        }
        // Request to login
        fwrite ( $socket, "AUTH LOGIN\r\n" );
        if ( $this->status_match ( $socket, "334" ) === false ) {
            return "Invalid SMTP configuration";
        }
        // Send the username
        fwrite ( $socket, base64_encode ( $config [ "username" ] ) . "\r\n" );
        if ( $this->status_match ( $socket, "334" ) === false ) {
            // If failed, warn that invalid username password was passed
            return "Invalid username/password combination.";
        }
        // Send the password
        fwrite ( $socket, base64_encode ( $config [ "password" ] ) . "\r\n" );
        if ( $this->status_match ( $socket, "235" )  === false ) {
            // If failed, warn that invalid username password was passed
            return "Invalid username/password combination.";
        }
        // Close the socket connections
        fclose ( $socket );
        // Return true, if everything above passed
        return true;
    }

    private function status_match ( $socket, $expected ) {
        // Initialize the response string
        $response = '';
        // Get response until nothing but code is visible
        while ( substr ( $response, 3, 1) != ' ' ) {
            // Receive 250 bytes
            if ( !( $response = fgets ( $socket, 256 ) ) ) {
                // Break if nothing else to read
                break;
            }
        }
        // If the status code is not what was expected
        if ( !( substr ( $response, 0, 3 ) == $expected ) ) {
            // Return false
            return false;
        }
        // Otherwise return true
        return true;
    }
```

I came up with this by using the following example: http://schoudhury.com/blog/articles/send-email-using-gmail-from-php-with-fsockopen/

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything in the [documentation](https://docs.zendframework.com/zend-mail/) that suggests that there's a way to just test the SMTP authentication without actually trying to send mail. Maybe when you call `setOptions` or `setConnectionConfig` it will attempt the login and throw an exception if it fails, but I suspect not.

Rather than perform the validation check every time you want to send mail, save the configuration data and validation results in a file. Then before making the SMTP check, read the file and check whether the configuration settings are the same. If they are, just return the saved results.

This solves the first two items in your list of problems, and they'll only get a bounce email the first time if their configuration is invalid.

Comment: Hey, you might have misunderstood my question.  I am trying to determine if a user's SMTP configuration is valid. So basically I want to log into the SMTP server with their credentials, but not send any mail.  There is nothing to check against.

Comment: Your script tries to send mail and checks whether it's successful. I'm suggesting that you keep that, but cache the result so you don't have to do it every time.

Comment: That's all good, but I would like to avoid that altogether.  Surely there is a way to do this in the Zend API right?  If there isn't I will have to resort to checking manually by opening a socket using the configuration supplied by the user, and then passing the EHLO and AUTH LOGIN commands.  I appreciate your answer, I will try to integrate that as well.

Comment: "Surely there is a way to do this". Read my first paragraph. I scanned the Zend documentation and didn't see anything that suggests that. If you see something I didn't, then you should be able to answer the question yourself.

Comment: My apologies, I only meant that it would be an intuitive functionality to have within the framework.  I guess I will have to check manually.  Thanks for your help and time :)

Comment: It seems reasonable, but I guess they just assume you know what you're doing when you configure it, and you'll handle errors when it fails. They didn't consider the need of a generic library that wants to check what the administrator is doing.